# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named msg1 (in ubuntu with python 2.7.6 is not showing any error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

Directory Structure

`test.py
 Info
   __init.py
   msg1.py
   msg2.py
   msg3.py`

test.py

```
import Info  
Info.msg1()  
Info.msg2()  
Info.msg3()
```

**init**.py

```
from msg1 import msg1  
from msg2 import msg2  
from msg3 import msg3
```

msg1.py

```
def msg1():  
print "This is msg1"
```

`msg2.py` and `msg3.py` is also same as `msg1.py`
me running this on windows pc with python 3.7.0

getting the below error[image: PackageError]

Please help me out

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why your program is breaking. Whenever a script is launched from your terminal, It appends the current path of the file to `sys.path` And Python only looks for modules which are in direct reach of this path. In your case, it appended to the path of the test.py, **But**, from the eyes of the Python interpreter, `msg1` is still `Info.` away from the directory of `test.py` that is because the `sys.path` has directory only up to `test.py` and not up to `Info` i.e, there is a *gap* in the directory chain. So to avoid this problem you need to use relative imports to avoid name dependencies. Change your `__init__` to this and it should work. **Or** you could also add the path of `Info` package to your `sys.path` which is not recommended but still possible.

```
from .msg1 import msg1
from .msg2 import msg2
from .msg3 import msg3
```

And here's another way you could do the same

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Info') # Or you could os module to get dynamically

from msg1 import msg1
from msg2 import msg2
from msg3 import msg3
```

Although a much better way would be this

```
import os
import sys
dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Info')
sys.path.append(dir)
```

And if you want to make the changes permanent, i.e not add `sys.path` every time, you can EXPORT or ADD the path to python's environment variables and it will pick it up automatically.

Comment: Thank you for u r explanation

Answer (score 0):

You would import with this syntax in __init__.py:

__init__.py

```
from Info.msg1 import msg1
from Info.msg2 import msg2
from Info.msg3 import msg3
```

Or you can use as :

```
from .msg1 import msg1
from .msg2 import msg2
from .msg3 import msg3
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you, Now it's working fine. msg1 is already in Info again y should i call like this from Info.msg1 import msg1. could u let me know the reason thank u

Comment: As per Python doc : when a submodules is loaded using any mechanism , a binding is placed in the parent module's namespace. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html check 5.4.2. Submodules topic.

Comment: Thank you really u saved my day